# How to tab the whole subitem?

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem

I'm typing up a document that requires subitems (ex: 1. a), b), etc.). I have been able to do this by using `\subitem` but what really bugs me is that only this first line of the subitem has a indent (tab) and what follows after does not conform to that indent. Does that make sense? Here's a picture of what I'm talking about in case it doesn't:

[image]

I tried using `\setlength{\parindent}{0.25cm}` but that didn't work. I am using the **enumitem** package, but I haven't looked into it very throughly so maybe there's something there that I haven't tried. I would really appreciate if anyone has any suggestions as to how to resolve this semi-annoying problem. Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT** The code I'm using (a portion of it):

```
\item \textit{CC DD} and \textit{cc dd} individuals were crossed to each other, and the $\mathrm{F_{1}}$ generation was backcrossed to the \textit{cc dd} parent. 903 \textit{Cc Dd}, 897 \textit{cc dd}, 98 \textit{Cc dd}, and 102 \textit{cc Dd} offspring resulted. 

\subitem a. How far apart are the \textit{c} and \textit{d} loci?

\subitem b. What progeny and in what frequencies would you expect to result from testcrossing the $\mathrm{F_{1}}$ generation from a \textit{CC dd} X \textit{cc DD} cross to \textit{cc dd}?
```

Comment: @Halime it would be helpful if you showed in a minimal example what code you were actually trying to use. (For example, `\subitem` is not defined by the `enumitem` package.)

Comment: @ Alan Munn -- Sorry! I'm still new to this. I'll add my code in my question above.

Comment: @Halime, rather than the actual text, you should try to make a small, complete document that shows what your problem is.  The example should be a *full document* (compilable), like the one I posted in my answer to you.  (Does that solve your problem, anyway?)

Comment: @Halime Also, the backtick delimeter is for short pieces of code inside regular text; to format a block of code, you can select it and click on the 101010 icon.  I fixed this in your question for you.

Comment: @ Alan Munn -- I tried doing that (putting the full document)... I guess that didn't work, but I used what you suggested and that worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help and for fixing the code it my post!

Comment: @Halime I'm glad it helped.  If the answer does in fact solve your problem, you should click on the checkmark to accept it.  This helps others who might have the same problem know that the answer should work for them too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just embed one `enumerate` environment in another:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for some dummy text
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\alph*.}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Nesting `itemize` works too.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item item-1
\item item-2
\begin{itemize}
\item item-2-1
\item item-2-2
\end{itemize}
\item item-3
\end{itemize}
```